# PHP make new Class Object inside foreach

Tags: php, class, object

I'm going crazy...
I have two PHP class, one that define a Gallery (with method like "add_media, get_media...") and the class Media.
All works fine, but if I do the new Media statement twice in the same time it breaks everything....

Here some code of my Classe

```
class Media {

private $id;
private $titolo;
private $alt;
private $src;
private $thumb;
private $modelli=array();
private $stato;
private $ordinamento=array();

function __construct($params) {
    if(isset($params['id'])){
    $this->id=$params['id'];
    }
    $this->titolo=$params['titolo'];
    $this->alt=$params['alt'];
    $this->src=$params['src'];
    $this->thumb=$params['thumb'];
    $this->modelli=$params['modelli'];
    $this->stato=$params['stato'];
    $this->ordinamento=$params['ordinamento'];
}


//function get media
    function get_media($id){
        $dbfile = __DIR__ . Galleria::DATABASE_LOCATION  . Galleria::DATABASE_NAME . ".db";
        // bind the database handler
        $this->database = new db("sqlite:" . $dbfile);
        $query="id = '".$id."'";
        $results = $this->database->select(Galleria::DATABASE_NAME, $query);

        return $results;
    }
```

The Galleria object is created once, then I call on that object multiple get_media()

Probably is a mistake in the Media class definition...any suggestion?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Please, can you clarify _All works fine, but if I do the new Media statement twice in the same time it breaks everything_?

Comment: Yes, if I retrieve a Media object with get_media(id) and print out the result or acess some properties it works. But if I do it again with another id it stop working and cannot load the page with connection error.